# Select a specific input box from multiple boxes which have the same HTML code

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to insert a container number in the first input box but the page has 3 and all have the same HTML code. How can I select only the first box? I tried a couple of things but I always get an error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='text'and @class='inputmember'][1]"}

HTML code:

```
<div id="cnfield1">

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <a class="new_btn02" href="javascript:makeField('cn');">+ADD</a>
</div>

<td class="text_R">
    <a class="new_btn03" id="resetBtn" href="#">Reset</a>
    <a class="new_btn08" id="inquiryBtn" href="#">Inquiry</a>
</td>
```

Python code:

```
Lst=['HDMU2795525']

if i == 'HYUNDAI':
    #HYUNDAI
    driver.get('https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/trackTrace/trackTrace/index')

    #element= WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
    expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputmember']")))

    for j in Lst:
        
        #Insert container number

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'and @class='inputmember'][1]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'and @class='inputmember'][1]").send_keys(j)
               
        #Search
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='inquiryBtn']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form is located inside an iframe so you need to switch to that frame before filling the form:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('_frame1')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' and @class='inputmember'][1]")
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the info, it worked! the only problem I have now after i clicked the button to search the information, is that the page is stuck in  "loading".

Comment: @GiancarloOtero can you check if `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='inquiryBtn']").submit()` works as expected?

Comment: I tried this change but the website stays with the container number filled in the input box and doesn't go to the next step, and python stays with an hourglass as if it was still running. Even when loading the page it is really really slow compared as to doing it manually, as if they know its an automated software and slow it down on purpose.